# in Info.plist , I have already added NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription with string. but still showing same error

Tags: ios, info.plist

In Info.plist I have already added `NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription` with string. But it still shows the same error:

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

How to solve this?

Comment: Show us proof that you have the proper entry in your Info.plist.

Comment: I am having the same issue, please let me know if you have figured it out

Comment: I am also facing same issue. @salma Did you find solution?

Answer (score 3):

Open the `info.plist` as source code and then add the code:

```
<key>NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription</key>
<string>recognize speech</string>
```

Comment: The question clearly states that this is already in the Info.plist.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using App test and App UItest then there would be multple plist files in your project just make it sure you are adding description in right **plist** which is inside your project folder.

[image]

circled one plist is right one which is in your project.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue, after adding **NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription** key app was crashing. In my project I have two **.plist files**. I was adding key on wrong plist file. Make sure you are adding key in correct .plist.

Answer (score 0):

I just got rid of the exact same error by asking for **microphone** access, i.e. adding the NS**Microphone**UsageDescription to the plist.

Sounds like an Apple bug to me, but hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the same issue
make sure you put your key and string on the root level of plist file

Comment: Please, don't post code as image.